# Sequence corresponding to the generating function

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

> Find the sequence corresponding to the generating function $$G(x) = \frac{2x^4}{2x^3-x^2-2x+1}$$

First of all, I wrote this equation like that;

$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty(a_n)x^n = \frac{2x^4}{2x^3-x^2-2x+1}$

Then, I think right hand side should be;

$\frac{2x^4}{2x^3-x^2-2x+1} = \frac{A}{2x-1} + \frac{B}{x-1} + \frac{C}{x+1}$

I found

$A = \frac{-2x^2}{3}$ , $B = x^2$ ,  $C = \frac{x^2}{3}$

However, I cannot continue after that point.

Comment: you've http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand+2x%5E4%2F%282x%5E3-x%5E2-2x%2B1%29+at+the+origin

Comment: or 2 times the https://oeis.org/A000975

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the partial fraction decomposition is correct (I haven't checked it, but I suppose you have), remember that $\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$. Hence $$\frac{1}{2x-1}=-\frac{1}{1-2x}=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty (2x)^n=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^nx^n$$
and $$\frac{1}{x-1}=-\frac{1}{1-x}=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$$
and $$\frac{1}{x+1}=\frac{1}{1-(-x)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nx^n$$
Remember also that multiplying a power series by $x^n$ shifts the coefficients $n$ steps upwards. Can you continue from here?

Comment: I only can't understand what should I do with $x^2$ components

Comment: Do you by "$x^2$-component" mean the factors $A,B,C$ which all are constant multiples of $x^2$? The last part of my response covers this: if $\sum_{i=0}^\infty b_ix^i$ is an arbitrary power series, then $x^2\sum_{i=0}^\infty b_ix^i=\sum_{i=0}^\infty b_ix^{i+2}=\sum_{i=2}^\infty b_{i-2}x^i$. So multiplying by $x^2$ shifts all coefficients two indices upwards.

Comment: Yes I meant them, but now everything is clear, sir

Comment: Good to hear :)