# How to derive sequence from generating function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

If you are solving a problem and you encounter a generating function that you haven't seen before, is there a way to derive its underlying sequence representation?

For example I came across $\frac{1}{1+x}$ and had to look it up to see that it had coefficients $(-1)^n$, but what if I encounter something that doesn't have a lookup somewhere? Is there a way I can actually generate the coefficient representation from the generating function without needing to resort to internet lookups?

Comment: I think you mean sequence, not series.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews What's the difference?

Comment: A series is a sequence of the form $x_1,x_1+x_2,x_1+x_2+x_3,\dots$. If you are looking for the coefficients of a generating function, you are seeking a sequence which is not (in general) a series.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Oh ok, then yes I am looking for the sequence

Comment: for what sequence do you want a generating function?

Comment: @janmarqz He wants to go the other way - from generating function to sequence.

Comment: There isn't a general rule, unfortunately, except for some simple classes of functions. For example, if $f(x)$ is the ration of two polynomials, you can use partial fractions to find the sequence.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Do you have a good link for all the classes you refer to?

Comment: take a minute of experimentations with http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand+%281-x%2Bx%5E2%29%2F%281%2B3x-x%5E2%29+at+the+origin

Comment: I tried "expand (1)/(1+x) at the origin" and at the bottom it says "Series representation" so now I am confused because earlier Thomas said it was a sequence

Comment: @janmarqz Also how does it derive the coefficients from something like $(1-x+x^2)/(1+3x-x^2)$?

Comment: had you ever heard about the Taylor's and/or  Maclaurin's series?

Comment: I have heard of them but I don't know how to use them or what they mean

Answer (score 1):

[This math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1569588/sequence-corresponding-to-the-generating-function) has a good example of the technique when you can decompose your function into partial fractions.

**Edit**: Using the example from your comment, $\dfrac{1-x+x^2}{1+3x-x^2} = -1-\dfrac{2x+2}{x^2-3x-1}$.

Solving $\dfrac{2x+2}{x^2-3x-1} = \dfrac{A}{x-\alpha}+\dfrac{B}{x-\beta}$ where $\alpha,\beta = \dfrac{3\pm\sqrt{13}}{2}$ yields $A=\dfrac{2\alpha+2}{\alpha-\beta},B=\dfrac{2\beta+2}{\beta-\alpha}$. Then $$-1-\dfrac{A}{x-\alpha}-\dfrac{B}{x-\beta} = -1+\dfrac{A}{\alpha}\dfrac{1}{1-\frac{1}{\alpha}x}+\dfrac{B}{\beta}\dfrac{1}{1-\frac{1}{\beta}x}=-1+\dfrac{A}{\alpha}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{\alpha^n}x^n+\dfrac{B}{\beta}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{\beta^n}x^n$$
$$=-1+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{A}{\alpha^{n+1}}+\frac{B}{\beta^{n+1}}\right)x^n$$
so the sequence is $a_0=1, a_{n\ge1} = \dfrac{A}{\alpha^{n+1}}+\dfrac{B}{\beta^{n+1}}=\dfrac{2^{n+1}}{\sqrt{13}}\left[\dfrac{5+\sqrt{13}}{(3+\sqrt{13})^{n+1}}-\dfrac{5-\sqrt{13}}{(3-\sqrt{13})^{n+1}}\right]$, which looks like it came from some fibonacci-like recurrence.